# What is this creeper with serrated leaves and small white flowers growing in Mumbai, India?

Tags: identification, ground-cover, creepers

What is this creeper?

Location: Mumbai, India (Tropics)

Conditions: Growing in the Monsoons from June-July onwards in heavy rains and waterlogged soil, overcast / full shade to full sun.

Other Details: Growing wild as ground cover. Looked like moss from afar, but has serrated leaves and is also sprouting tiny green buds which become lavender bulbs which turn into small white flowers with 4-6 pointed petals. Please refer images.

Long view below
[image: Long view]
Close up 1 below
[image: Close up 1]
Close up 2 below
[image: Close up 2]

Edit:

Close up of leaves and flowers below
[image: Close up of leaves]
One small plant sample below
[image: One small plant sample]
Close up of flowers below:
[image: Close up of flowers 1]
Close up of flowers below... NOTE in the centre of the image the spiky leaf flower next to mild lavender colored one...i think the lavender flower becomes spiky when it gets older, not sure.
[image: Close up of flowers 2]

Comment: Can you try to get us some close up pictures of the leaves and/or describe their edges. Are they smooth or jagged? Are more than one species growing intertwined?

Comment: More close ups added on a good sunny day. Edges are serrated/jagged. As seen in the long shot, there are other plants around it, but in all the photos, the plant in focus is just this one and its not intertwined with plants of other species in the photos.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it's one of the speedwells, or Veronicas - it would be very helpful to see a close up shot of an open flower to assist with ID, but it could be Veronica agrestis (field speedwell) Veronica persica or Veronica filiformis [(creeping speedwell)](http://www.massey.ac.nz/massey/learning/colleges/college-of-sciences/clinics-and-services/weeds-database/creeping-speedwell.cfm).

Some of these are common turf weeds in other parts of the world, but they grow quite happily in borders or open ground too.

If you can manage to get a clear shot of an open flower, please add to your question.

Comment: I've added some flower shots. Unfortunately this is the best my camera can do. Please note in the centre of the last image the spiky leaf flower next to mild lavender colored one...i think the lavender flower becomes spiky when it gets older, not sure.

Comment: Shape-wise, leaves are like Veronica agrestis. But the leaves on this plant are glossy unlike the speedwells, which all seem to have hairy leaves.

The flower looks similar to the Veronica agrestis shown in the link you provided, but I had a look on the net for more photos of Veronica agrestis flowers and it looks blue and quite different there.

Comment: There are an awful lot of Veronicas, but I agree this may not be an actual Veronica, although its the closest I could think of. It also reminds me of the Campanulas, but as to which one it might be, I'm unable to identify it. 'Weed' plants are often native versions, so my resources for weeds and wildflowers are unlikely to show one that's growing where you are, if it's not widespread in the world (which the Veronicas are, slightly different varieties occur in many countries) but you may have a bellflower (Campanula) that I know nothing about...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the updates with the photos. I think you have the Mazus reptans, which has its origins in the Himalayas. Can you look at some photos and tell me if this is your plant?

Comment: From photos of mazus reptans on the net, the leaves start narrow and end roundish, while the leaves in my photos start broad and end in a point. Both are serrated though, but different shapes.Flowers are completely different.